# How to lock entire rows based on a certain word in a column without using Table in dataset

Tags: vba, excel

I am aiming to lock entire rows where the word "Done" appears in a specific column. My code below achieves what I seek but it takes 18 seconds to compute (too long). Is there a faster/more efficient coding alternative?

There is an existing question on StackOverflow similar to this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664561/vba-to-lock-entire-row-based-on-a-word-in-a-column)) but my data does not exist in defined tables (this won't change), so I don't know how to adapt the suggestion there.

```
Private Sub Lock_Rows(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long ' Integer

Set DestSh = Worksheets(8) 'Data tab for Item 1

With DestSh
    'finds the last row with data on B column, B column has dates
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'parse all rows
    For i = 26 To lastrow 'rows of data begin at row 26
       'if your conditions are met
       If .Cells(i, "Z").Value = "Done" Then
          .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow.Cells.Locked = True 'lock the row
          Else
          .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow.Cells.Locked = False 'leave rows unlocked
       End If
    Next i
    .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End With
Set DestSh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lock / Unlock operations om individual rows are quite slow.  Better to build a range reference to Lock / Unlock and do that operation in on go at the end.

Something like

```
Private Sub Lock_Rows(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long ' Integer
    Dim rLock As Range, rUnlock As Range
    Set DestSh = Worksheets(8) 'Data tab for Item 1

    With DestSh
        'finds the last row with data on B column, B column has dates
        lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'parse all rows
        For i = 26 To lastrow 'rows of data begin at row 26
            'if your conditions are met
            If .Cells(i, "Z").Value = "Done" Then
                If rLock Is Nothing Then
                    Set rLock = .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow
                Else
                    Set rLock = Application.Union(rLock, .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow)
                End If
            Else
                If rUnlock Is Nothing Then
                    Set rUnlock = .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow
                Else
                    Set rUnlock = Application.Union(rUnlock, .Cells(i, "Z").EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not rLock Is Nothing Then rLock.Locked = True
        If Not rUnlock Is Nothing Then rUnlock.Locked = False
        .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End With
    Set DestSh = Nothing
End Sub
```

It will be faster still you could incorporate use of Variant Arrays on the loop

On my hardware it takes about 6 s to process 500,000 rows

Comment: Are you sure your solution is that efficient? are you sure it is more efficient than original one? I do some tests and original takes 32 sec while your is going to take over 5 minutes.... where is the problem??

Comment: In my tests the original code took several minutes.   This will depend on the nature of the data.  Can you post how many rows of data you have, and some idea of the distribution of the "Done"s

Comment: I tested approx. 100k rows with values like *A*,*B*, *C*, *Done* where *Done* was every 9th row.

Comment: I only have around 150 rows, and Chris' solution takes less than 2 seconds and Kazimierz' takes around 3 seconds - regardless of distribution of 'Done's! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** to add a faster solution combining `Sort()` and `AutoFilter()`

---

`AutoFilter()` can make things fast:

```
Private Sub Lock_Rows(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Worksheets(8)
        If IsEmpty(.Range("Z25")) Then .Range("Z25").Value = "xxx" ' be sure you have a column "header" for data in column Z from row 26 downwards
        With .Range("Z25:Z" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            .EntireRow.Locked = False ' unlock all cells
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Done"
            With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, .EntireColumn).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Locked = True ' lock only filtered range rows
            End With
        End With
        If .Range("Z25").Value = "xxx" Then .Range("Z25").ClearContents ' remove any "not original" column header
    End With
End Sub
```

if you know that cell Z25 content is always not empty then you can omit the lines:

```
If IsEmpty(.Range("Z25")) Then .Range("Z25").Value = "xxx"

If .Range("Z25").Value = "xxx" Then .Range("Z25").ClearContents
```

---

and if you Sort things, it's even faster:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Lock_Rows(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dataRange As Range, sortRange As Range, lockRange As Range

    With Worksheets("8") ' reference wanted sheet
        Set dataRange = .Range("Z25", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set lockRange = Intersect(.Columns("Z"), dataRange)
        Set sortRange = Intersect(dataRange.EntireRow, .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1)) ' reference the range in same rows as referenced one but in first "not used" column
        Set dataRange = .Range(dataRange, sortRange)
    End With

    With sortRange
        .Formula = "=ROW()" ' write rows indexes in referenced range. this will be used to sort things back
        .Value = .Value ' get rid of formulas
    End With

    dataRange.Sort key1:=lockRange.Resize(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes ' sort data on columns with possible "Done" values

    If IsEmpty(lockRange(1, 1)) Then lockRange(1, 1).Value = "xxx" ' remove any "not original" column header
    With dataRange ' reference referenced sheet column B range in

        .AutoFilter field:=lockRange.Column - Columns(1).Column, Criteria1:="Done"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Locked = True ' lock only filtered range rows
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .Sort key1:=sortRange.Resize(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes ' sort things back
        sortRange.ClearContents ' delete rows index, not needed anymore
    End With
    If lockRange(1, 1).Value = "xxx" Then lockRange(1, 1).ClearContents ' remove any "not original" column header
End Sub
```

again, if you know that cell Z25 content is always not empty then you can omit the lines:

```
If IsEmpty(lockRange(1, 1)) Then lockRange(1, 1).Value = "xxx" ' remove any "not original" column header

If lockRange(1, 1).Value = "xxx" Then lockRange(1, 1).ClearContents ' remove any "not original" column header
```

Comment: When I tried this solution, only completely empty rows ended up being locked/protected, but it filtered all 'Done's and hid rows where 'Done' was not found. This wasn't what I was looking for but it was educational and indeed a tool for much faster processing. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t get you: in my test all column Z cells from row 25 downwards with “Done” content get locked. And the filter is removed. Did you change your data layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution which seems to be much faster than original one:

```
Private Sub Lock_Rows_new(ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print "s:" & Timer
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long ' Integer

    Set DestSh = Worksheets(8) 'Data tab for Item 1

    With DestSh
        'range to search

        Dim firstRNGRow As Variant  '!! important
            firstRNGRow = 26

        Dim firstRNG As Range
        Set firstRNG = .Cells(firstRNGRow, "Z")

        Dim lastRNG As Range
        Set lastRNG = .Cells(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "Z")

        'unlock all
            Range(firstRNG, lastRNG).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = False

        'search for first done
            firstRNGRow = Application.Match("Done", Range(firstRNG, lastRNG), 0)

        Do While (Not IsError(firstRNGRow))
            Set firstRNG = .Cells(firstRNG.Row + firstRNGRow, "Z")

            firstRNG.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = True 'lock the row

            If firstRNG.Row > lastRNG.Row Then Exit Do

            firstRNGRow = Application.Match("Done", Range(firstRNG, lastRNG), 0)


        Loop

        .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End With
    Set DestSh = Nothing
    Debug.Print "e:" & Timer
End Sub
```